# Generating a set of random numbers

Tags: c, random, file-handling

Problem Statement: Create three input files: INPUT01.DAT, INPUT02.DAT, INPUT03.DAT, each having 100 random numbers.
Read from each of these input files, and output the odd and even numbers in two files: ODD.TXT, EVEN.TXT, mentioning the name of the source file.

```
int main()

{
    FILE *fp1,*fp2,*fp3,*g,*h;
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    int i, noofr, j ,k,l,num[110];
    g= fopen("EVENq13.TXT","a+");
    h= fopen("ODDq13.TXT","a+");


    printf ( "Enter number of records: " ) ;
    scanf ( "%d", &noofr ) ;
    fp1= fopen ( "INPUT01.TXT", "w+" ) ;
    fp2= fopen ( "INPUT02.TXT", "w+" ) ;
    fp3= fopen ( "INPUT03.TXT", "w+" ) ;
    if ( fp1 == NULL||fp2==NULL||fp3==NULL )
    {
        printf ( "Unable to create file." ) ;
        getch( ) ;
        exit ( 0 ) ;
    }

    for ( i = 0 ; i < noofr ; i++ )
    {
        j = rand() % 100 + 1;         
        fprintf(fp1,"%d\t",j);
    }

    for ( i = 0 ; i < noofr ; i++ )
    {
         k= rand() % 100 + 1;
        fprintf(fp2,"%d\t",j);
    }

    for ( i = 0 ; i < noofr ; i++ )
    {   l= rand() % 100 + 1;
         fprintf(fp3,"%d\t",j);
    }

    fclose ( fp1 ) ;
     fclose ( fp2) ;
      fclose ( fp3 ) ;

    fp1 = fopen ( "INPUT01.TXT", "r" ) ;
    fp2 = fopen ( "INPUT02.TXT", "r" ) ;
    fp3 = fopen ( "INPUT03.TXT", "r" ) ;

    fprintf(g,"\n\n Nos from INPUT01 \n");
   fprintf(h,"\n\n Nos from INPUT01 \n");

    for(i=0;i<noofr;i++)
    {fscanf(fp1,"%d ",&num[i]);
     if (num[i]%2==0)
     {
        fprintf(g,"%d\t",num[i]);
     }
     else
     {
        fprintf(h,"%d\t",num[i]);
     }
    }


    fprintf(g,"\n\n Nos from INPUT02 \n");
    fprintf(h,"\n\n Nos from INPUT02 \n");


    for(i=0;i<noofr;i++)
    {fscanf(fp2,"%d ",&num[i]);
     if (num[i]%2==0)
     {
        fprintf(g,"%d\t",num[i]);
     }
     else
     {
        fprintf(h,"%d\t",num[i]);
     }
    }
    fprintf(g,"\n\n Nos from INPUT03 \n");
    fprintf(h,"\n\n Nos from INPUT03 \n");


    for(i=0;i<noofr;i++)
    {fscanf(fp3,"%d ",&num[i]);
     if (num[i]%2==0)
     {
        fprintf(g,"%d\t",num[i]);
     }
     else
     {
        fprintf(h,"%d\t",num[i]);
     }
    }




    fclose ( fp1 ) ;
     fclose ( fp2) ;
      fclose ( fp3 ) ;
    fclose(g);
    fclose(h);
    printf ( "\nFile is created. \nPress any key to continue." ) ;
    getch();
}
```

The second and third set of numbers become constant instead of being random and the constant is usually the last number of the first set of numbers.

I know I am going wrong on setting the seed. Is it possible to rectify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second and third `fprintf()` calls to reference the correct variable. In other words, from this:

```
fprintf(fp2,"%d\t",j);
```

to this:

```
fprintf(fp2,"%d\t",k);
```

and from this:

```
fprintf(fp3,"%d\t",j);
```

to this:

```
fprintf(fp3,"%d\t",l);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. noobish mistake, mybad :/